# How to point a domain to a fake subdomain?

Tags: php, .htaccess, dns, subdomain

my system works like this: client1.mysite.com, cliente2.mysite.com. 
But this subdomains doesnt really exists. They are pointed by htaccess rules.

Now i want to point a domain (like client1.com) on other server to the client account (client1.mysite.com).

What I did o client1.com DNS zone:
1. create cname www to client1.mysite.com
2. create cname @ (or . or empty) to client1.mysite.com

What do I have to do next on my server? Is something on DNS or htaccess?

Tks!

Comment: Are you using any form of hosting control panel, such as plesk or cpanel?

Comment: If I understood correctly, client1.com and client2.com are managed by you. You want to redirect the visitors of client1.com and client2.com to client1.mysite.com and client2.mysite.com respectively. To do it simply, there are two ways. First is by add redirect on the domain client1.com control panel. In case you have a hosting connected to this domain, then why not add a PHP/ASP file to take care of the redirect? This way you are doing it without interfering with any important domain/server settings.

Comment: @LewisBrowne I'm using cpanel

Comment: @MohammedAkhtarZuberi cliente1.com and client2.com is managed by me but they are in a diffent server.
The problem is that client1.com dont reach the destination. I have to do somenthing more that I dont know what.

Comment: Have I understood correctly that the destination of client1.com is client1.mysite.com and client2.com is client2.mysite.com? In addition to this, all the three websites are on three different servers. Correct?

Comment: correct @MohammedAkhtarZuberi